# Check combination of values in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, function, compare

I have three *columns* (input1, input2, input3), I need to compare them and check that there is not a combination of the values already registered in the database.

I need to return `true` when they are all the same or when they are all different. In intermediate cases, return `false`.

I tried:

```
public function check($input1, $input2, $input3) {
    if (Model::where('input1', 'LIKE', $input1)->where('input2', 'LIKE', $input2)->where('input3', '=', $input3)->exists()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (Model::where('input1', '=', $input1)->where('input3', '!=', $input3)->exists()) {
            return true;
        }

        if (Model::where('input1', '!=', $input1)->where('input3', '=', $input3)->exists()) {
            return true;
        }

        if (Model::where('input1', '=', $input1)->where('input3', '=', $input3)->exists()) {
            return true;
        }
    }  
}
```

Not being met when `input1` and `input3` are registered, but no `input2` is found in the table.

How can I solve it, the idea is to compare the three inputs.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**:

I tried:

```
public function check($input1, $input2, $input3) {
        if (Model::where('input1', '=', $input1)->where('input3', '!=', $input3)->exists()) {
            return true;
        }
        if (Model::where('input1', '!=', $input1)->where('input3', '=', $input3)->exists()) {
            return true;
        }
        if (Model::where('input1', '=', $input1)->where('input3', '=', $input3)->exists()) {
            return true;
        }
        if (Model::where('input1', '!=', $input1)->where('input3', '!=', $input3)->exists()) {
            return false;
        }
}
```

I need to correct the above so that I can validate when all three values match a record.

**UPDATE**:

I need to validate according to the image

[image: UPDATE]

**UPDATE**:

is an example of what i need to do

[image]

**UPDATE**:

A resolution strategy could be, to verify only the cases when the three values coincide completely or when they are totally different

```
public function check($input1, $input2, $input3)
{            
    // initialization
    $temp1=true;
    $temp1=true;
    
    if (Model::where('input1', '=' ,$input1)->whereDate('input2', '=' ,$input2)->where('input3', '=' ,$input3)->exists()){
        return true;
    } else {
        $temp1=false;
    }
    
    if ($temp1=false && Model::where('input1', '!=' ,$input1)->whereDate('input2', '!=' ,$input2)->where('input3', '!=' ,$input3)->exists()){
        return true;
    } else {
        $temp2=false;
    }
    
    if ($temp1=false && $temp2=false){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I do not understand your problem, what does "Not being met when value1 and value3 are registered, but no value2 is found in the table." mean? Can you translate it better ? Also, you can "join" all 3 last queries (the ones that will return `true`), so you do 1 query instead of 3. And one more thing, if you have 2 columns to check, that means 4 checks, you are doing 3, what happens for the last one ? And you are not returning `false` or anything in the case that `value1` is `!=` and `value3` is `!=` (that is your 4th state not checked).

Comment: Hi @matiaslauriti, thanks for your response. Yes, basically what I want is to compare the three columns and return false when trying to load a new record and some of the fields match the saved data. Return true when all are equal to a record already saved or all are different. Could you rewrite what I did, adding the missing conditional and optimizing the code. thank you!

Comment: So, if any of `value1` or `value2` or `value3` exists (do an exact check like `==` and not `LIKE`, right ?) you want to return `false`, but if all of those values do not exist in the database, you want to return `true` ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti yes, how should I rewrite the function?

Comment: Did my solution work ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti I updated the question. I did not find what you shared for all validations. What I tried (see update) works for almost all cases, it just isn't working when all three values match a saved record. It has to return true.

Note: the value2 is a date field (YYYY-MM-DD).

Comment: and validate when value1 and value3 are equal, but value2 is different from their values in the table.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I need to validate according to the image (updated the question), you can help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: I am going to update my answer with your code updated to have it a little more "beautiful"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you can do it in one simple query, what you want (logically speaking) is an SQL query like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (
    (value1 = ?) OR
    (value2 = ?) OR
    (value3 = ?)
)
```

If this returns 1 row or more, then you want to return `false`. So, you can take advantage of [`exists`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#determining-if-records-exist) method. It will use [`EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) SQL method or whatever is called.

So, you can do 2 different things, the first one I am going to show is the same you are doing, but I don't know if you are using this in a controller, so you could use it in a [`FormRequest`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation) or [`validator`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manually-creating-validators).

---

#### Your way

```php
public function check($value1, $value2, $value3)
{
   return !Model::where('value1', $value1)->where('value2', $value2)->where('value3', $value3)->exists();
}
```

See that I wrote `!` before `Clientes`, so if these data exists, `exists()` will return `true`, but you want to opposite in this case.

#### Another way

Now, if you want to use it in a `validator` or a `FormRequest`, where you write the rules, you should have something like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

Validator::validate(
    [
        'value1' => $value1,
        'value2' => $value2,
        'value3' => $value3,
    ],
    [
        'value1' => 'unique:clientes',
        'value2' => 'unique:clientes',
        'value3' => 'unique:clientes',
    ]
);
```

Take in mind that, to do the inverse of `exists`, we use `unique`. If any of the values exist, then it will throw an error and return to the view (but this should only be used in `Controller`s or `FormRequest`s (rules, not `validator` literally)).

---

Update:

To have a better code, do this:

```php
public function check($input1, $input2, $input3)
{
    if (Model::where('input1', $input1)->whereDate('input2', $input2)->where('input3', $input3)->exists()) {
        return true;
    } else if (Model::where('input1', '!=', $input1)->whereDate('input2', '!=', $input2)->where('input3', '!=', $input3)->exists()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Still, this query could get better just doing one into two, but I am not 100% sure how to write that now.

And still makes not much sense (at least to me) to check if it exactly matches a row (at least with some fields), or totally the opposite, don't match any row with those values. It is a XOR gate but makes no sense.

Comment: thanks for your help. The first way works the same way as what I implemented, much simpler. But it still does not validate (see image 5) when the three entered fields all match a database. That case should be reviewed

Comment: I don't see how this is not working, I asked you that if `value1` or `value2` or `value3` exists, return `false`. You said that is what you want. Now you are saying that if ALL values exists, then return false again ? That is already in place as if any value exists, it will return `false`. You will have to explain better with real fields what are you trying to do as the image says nothing.

Comment: How is the last part of the image valid, if all 3 values exists ? I do not understand now...

Comment: In short, it should only be valid when they all match a record in the database, or when they are different. When one or two matches but the rest do not, it will not be valid. This is because once this is validated, other things are validated in the case of having a valid case.

Comment: Then it is `value1` **and** `value2` **and** `value3`, not `value1` **or** `value2` **or** `value3`. To do so, change my original code from `orWhere` to `where` and that's it.

Comment: Wait, now you are confusing me.... If it is valid for you when all 3 values matches, then you don't have to return `false`... it is contradictory...

Comment: sure, it's a bit confusing if you see it with the naked eye, but you have to do those validations as shown in the image. The problem is only a part of what I am developing, if there is a valid result, continue with other validations

Comment: I will make you a diagram so that it is understood, wait

Comment: Hi @matiaslauriti, I posted an update to the question, in the diagram you can see more simply what to do. Thank you!

Comment: It is still confusing, it says "is there a record in the database?" and case 5 there is not, the only thing that matches es `age` and still returns true. It is really strange, there is hidden logic there :(

Comment: It happens that in the first instance not all the columns are validated, only the first three, depending on how they result, the one that is missing is validated. The cases are the different cases that could exist for a given combination, there may be more than one record in the db, I only put one as an example.

Comment: Thank you ! I had another view and I am still confused. There is something wrong/strange with the logic. I see you do this: "Hey, does these 3 values exists on the database as a whole record? if yes, go check if the age in the database is greater than the form" so you get the record back and you check if the database age is greater than the form, that's okay. But I still am not sure what you need, I mean, why doing `value1 === $value1 AND value2 === $value2 AND value3 === $value3` does not work for you ? What do you need to check if that check is false ?

Comment: yes, using the first way you have proposed, it just doesn't work for the case that all fields match exactly. What we can do: a statement to check when all are different and another when all are equal, let's say there is no intermediate case when one or more value does not match. Then we see those intermediate cases.

Comment: we can do that, two statements, one for when all match exactly and another when none match exactly. return true in those cases ... and if it is neither, return false.

Comment: I updated the question, I inserted the function that we could use to solve. I need to check only those two cases

Comment: thanks for updating the code. It is not entering any of the ifs, and it goes directly to the last return. Why don't you check, does the issue have something to do with input2 being a date?

Comment: it is possible, how is `$value2` (date) formated ?

Comment: try using `where` instead of `whereDate` just to test.

Comment: I have removed the date field, and it is done. In another moment I will see that specific case. Thank you very much for your time, I appreciate it a lot!